# StringListProperty in GAE

Tags: python, google-app-engine

Is there any way to edit StringListProperty fields via Google's Data Viewer, or some other clever approach?

The last I want to do is to modify my application in such way that it provides special throwaway page for just that reason - I don't feel like it's the optimal solution.

Cheers,

MH

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would recommend using the [Remote API](http://code.google.com/appengine/articles/remote_api.html); you can edit anything in your datastore with a minimum of fuss and no special pages needed.